# Join on JPQL, CreateQuery

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, playframework, jpql

Trying to figure out how the join on JPQL CreateQuery works. I have a partial search function for manager name with the SQL code:

```
SELECT
e.EMPLOYEE_ID      AS empId,
e.FIRST_NAME       AS empFirstName,
e.LAST_NAME        AS empLastName,
m.FIRST_NAME || ' ' || m.LAST_NAME AS empMgrName
FROM
EMPLOYEES e
LEFT JOIN
EMPLOYEES m ON e.MANAGER_ID = m.EMPLOYEE_ID
WHERE
LOWER(m.FIRST_NAME || ' ' || m.LAST_NAME) LIKE '%"ManagerName"%'
```

I tried to make this into a JPQL format and i came up with the following:

```
StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder();
query.setLength(0);
query.append(" FROM ");
query.append("    Employee e  ");
query.append(" JOIN ");
query.append("    e.Manager m  ");
query.append(" WHERE 1 = 1 ");
query.append("    LOWER(m.FIRST_NAME || ' ' || m.LAST_NAME) LIKE :empMgrName ");
Query listEmpQuery = JPA.em().createQuery(query.toString(), Employee.class);
if (!StringUtil.isNullOrEmpty(strMgr)) {
  listEmpQuery.setParameter("empMgrName", "%" + strMgr.toLowerCase() + "%");
}
List<Employee> listEmp = listEmpQuery.getResultList();
```

Let say that the user entered the value of "ill gat" to the `strMgr` to search for the manager name "Bill Gates". It should search the employee that is under the manager bill gates. But in this code the ff error occurs:

```
IllegalArgumentException: Cannot create TypedQuery for query with more than one return using requested result type [models.db.Employee]]
```

What did I do wrong?

Reference:
Employee.class

```
@Entity
@Table(name="EMPLOYEES")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "EMPLOYEES_SEQ", sequenceName = "EMPLOYEES_SEQ")
public class Employee {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "EMPLOYEES_SEQ")
public Integer EMPLOYEE_ID;

public String FIRST_NAME;

public String LAST_NAME;

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name="MANAGER_ID")
public Employee Manager;
```

I self join the manager to Employee as "Manager"

Comment: Might as well take look at the Java Naming Conventions, especially for your attribute names. Take a look at the Variables part: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html

Comment: JPQL starts with "SELECT {alias}", any JPQL docs would tell you that. "||" is invalid JPQL, but there is a CONCAT function. This doc would tell you that too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thing is that when you have more than one entity in the query then you have to specify which one you want as the result (unless its a projection).

```
query.append(" SELECT e")
query.append(" FROM ");
query.append("    Employee e  ");
query.append(" JOIN ");
query.append("    e.Manager m  ");
```

or `SELECT m` if you want to have the manager as the result.

The `LIKE` clause is fine.. its built to prevent sql injection.

Comment: You changed this from an outer join to an inner join. And I think it is good practice to make FETCH JOINS fetch joins to avoid duplication of data in ManyToOne relationships.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to achieve is LEFT OUTER FETCH JOIN:

```
query.append("SELECT e FROM ");
query.append("    Employee e  ");
query.append("LEFT JOIN FETCH ");
query.append("    e.Manager");
query.append(" WHERE LOWER(CONCAT(m.FIRST_NAME, ' ', m.LAST_NAME)) LIKE :empMgrName ");
```